# How to get rid of error when using class inside class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm not much in TypeScript and encounter an issue. The code looks as following:

**1) Main.ts:**

```
import gpbApi from '@/utils/api/gpbApi';

@Component
export default class ExtendedDetailAccountComponent extends mixins(CurrentUserMixin) {
  ...
  async created() {
    try {
      console.log('gpbApi =', gpbApi);
      const result = await gpbApi.leadService.getReqtypes();
      console.log('result =', result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error = ', error);
    }
  }
  ...
```

**2) vue.d.ts:**

```
import gpbApi from './utils/api/gpbApi';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $gpbApi: typeof gpbApi;
  }
}
```

**3) gpbApi.ts:**

```
import leadService from '@/utils/api/leadService';

class GpbApi {
  leadService!: typeof leadService;
}

const instance = new GpbApi();
export default instance;
```

**4) leadService.ts:**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const path = '...';

class LeadService {
  async getReqtypes() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${path}/Reqtype`, { withCredentials: true });
    return data.data;
  }
}

const instance = new LeadService();
export default instance;
```

I get an error:

```
leadService: undefined
```

```
error =  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getReqtypes')
    at VueComponent.created
```

How to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically never instantiate leadService field of GpbApi if I am see it correctly.

So, you should instantiate `loadService` field in `gpbApi`

```
class GpbApi {
  leadService = leadService;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing ***typeof*** word from interface properties declaration like:

```
interface Vue {
  $gpbApi: gpbApi;
}
```

and the same with class definition:

```
class GpbApi {
  leadService!: leadService;
}
```